# Capitalise the first letter of every word as user types unless user insists on lower case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I am working on the script where I want the first letter and the letter after a space to be capitalized. If a word follows a hyphen (-), it should not be capitalized until and unless a space follows after the hyphen (-). If the user wants to lower case the first letter of any word, it should work dynamically.

This I achieved using the below script.

**The challenge here is, that it should be possible for the user to change the uppercased letter to a lower case while typing**

I am not able to achieve that feature.

Example:

If the user types "hello world", the output will be "Hello World", and if the user wants to lower case the letter "W"  from the word "World" by deleting the letter "W" and retyping the letter "w", the expected result should be "Hello world".

```js
$.fn.capitalize = function() {
  $.each(this, function() {
    var split = this.value.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {
      split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1);
    }
    this.value = split.join(' ');
  });
  return this;
};

$('textarea').on('keyup', function() {
  $(this).capitalize();
}).capitalize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Perhaps keep an array of typed values, if a value changes to lowercase from uppercase, flag it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulty will be in determining whether the user "corrects" an uppercase back to a lowercase equivalent or is making changes with other intentions. For instance, what if the user continues to change other characters of the original word, should the first letter be converted to upper case again? This, and many other scenarios, may lead to unexpected results for the user.

I would suggest an alternative, where you wait for the user to type a white space, and then capitalise the first letter of *only* the word that *precedes* that white space. Then, if the user goes back and makes it a lower case again, it will stay like that. The user must type a space (or newline, or tab) to trigger the automatic capitalisation again on the preceding word.

Here is how that would work:

```js
$.fn.capitalize = function() {
    $.each(this, function() {
        var pos = this.selectionStart,
            s = this.value,
            i = s.lastIndexOf(' ', pos-1)+1;
        // Don't do anything if text is selected
        if (this.selectionEnd !== pos) return;
        // Uppercase first character of word
        this.value = s.substr(0, i) + s.charAt(i).toUpperCase() + s.substr(i+1);
        // Restore caret position
        this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = pos;
    });
    return this;
};

$('textarea').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (' \n\r\t'.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) > -1) {
        $(this).capitalize();
    }
});
```

```css
textarea { width: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be achieved as user types .

Please have a look at

Comment: Is there any way this can be achieved as user types, instead of triggering event on press of space key for multiple inputs with same class name and pre-define values.

Please have a look at the link below

i have achieved for one input

http://jsfiddle.net/madhudvmask007/xj595z74/9/

If i use multiple input with predefined values i am getting issue . please have a look at the code below.

http://jsfiddle.net/madhudvmask007/xj595z74/6/

@trincot

Comment: If you want to work like that (which I would not advise), then store `prevEntry` as a data property of the element instead of using a global variable: `var prevEntry = $(this).data('prevEntry') || ''` and update it when needed: `$(this).data('prevEntry', finalValue)`.

Comment: Please check this .

http://jsfiddle.net/madhudvmask007/p4srb3mq/

Problem here is if i am using cursor pointer the delete first letter. After i delete the first letter cursor is pointing at the end of the string.
I want string to be placed at the start if start.
Need solution for this.

Thank you!!

Comment: I mean first letter of only first word. second , third word s first letter is working fine.

Comment: That is because you do `position || this.value.length;`. Think of what happens when position is 0. But I hope you understand I cannot keep answering questions in these comments. If you have a new question, please ask it using the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

jsfiddle.net/madhudvmask007/p4srb3mq

Problem here is, If i am using cursor pointer the delete first letter. After i delete the first letter cursor is pointing at the end of the string. I want pointer to be placed at the start if start.
Need solution for this.

Thank you!!

Comment: I mean first letter of only first word. second , third word s first letter is working fine.

Answer (score -2):

There you go :)

```
function useName (str) {
  if(!str) return '';
  return str
  .split(' ')
  .map(function (word) {
    if(word && word[0])
      return (word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1).toLowerCase());
     else
      return '';
   })
  .join(' ')
}
```

Comment: How does that answer the question? Maybe read the question up to the end?